# Fluent1 API - How to add default date while passing null value in date filed (1900-01-01)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, fluent

How to add default value for date field through fluent API entity framework in .net core.
my code is below :-

```
builder.Property(e => e.DOB)
.HasColumnType("date")
.HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
```

but this not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to add default value for date field through fluent API entity
> framework in .net core

Actually, defualt date value can be generated in various ways. In other words,  entity framework  core providers usually don't set up value generation automatically for date/time columns - you have to configure this yourself.

In addition, based on your scenario, you could do as following:

```
builder.Property(e => e.DOB).HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
```

**Note:** For more details, you could [have a look at this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#datetime-value-generation).